# Opening URL in specified Firefox profile from command line

Tags: command-line, firefox, command-line-arguments

Is there a way how I can let Firefox open a link in new tab from command line for specified profile? Ideally in a way in which it doesn't matter, whether Firefox is already running or not

I know I can do something like:

```
firefox --new-tab 'https://www.google.com'
```

This works no matter whether Firefox is already running (just add new tab) or it's not (open Firefox and add tab)

But what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
firefox -P myProfile --new-tab 'https://www.google.com
```

Where `myProfile` is existing profile.

This works unless Firefox is running with that profile (opens new instance). But if it's already running I get the error message (Firefox is already running but it's not responding. To use Firefox you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile).
I tried it with/without `--no-remote options` but it didn't help

I want this for a script that should open pages automatically but not in the default profile. And it should be able to work even if the profile is already running.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/119014/how-to-remotely-open-an-url-in-firefox-in-a-specific-profile/1821803#1821803 , solution there (is linked).